# Clojure: Combine hash-maps only if key is in both maps?

Tags: merge, clojure

I have two hash maps and am trying to merge them together while only keeping the keys found in both maps.
Ex:

```
{a true, b true, c true, d true, e true}
merged with {c true, d true, e true, f true}
would yield {c true, d true, e true}
```

I am pretty new to Clojure and just can't seem to figure out how to do this.  Thanks

Comment: How are you merging the values? You can use `select-keys` to select the keys you need from the second map.

Comment: Thats what I need help with.  I want to merge them as I showed in the code but I can't figure out how to do so

Comment: So you just want to discard the first map? Or do you want to combine the corresponding values in some way? It's not clear how `a => true` in the first map and `a => true` in the second combine to result in `a => true` in the result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a [select-keys](https://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?bu=uniq15181024801203631107&from=yandex.ru%3Bsearch%2F%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=1691.A0D4xhPywbpDlJZoS4QPq1m9dC3iLqjih5EXgLYeCA2ouIExGklamDVLXdL7d7Dg.96ec8d865016a85fc2644b4800cf62436013c6ad&uuid=&state=PEtFfuTeVD5kpHnK9lio9dFa2ePbDzX7fH_cbK-eu2V8J4cbFpzDXVHZJKQvpytSIkjSZ4Cc6zu0NMQINCoRdw,,&&cst=AiuY0DBWFJ5fN_r-AEszk9coEV7UpifkDx62yquvTQJ727miDnhtA-_IsIgMfhS04A5PijzBfM_oVaQEIDg3xDCUieQDzEAJK33sdyvF-sJ-8hsiINhs73_G_3OtisyNatItt0z0ynaom3YuuJUHzOtOU5X1iWlydEiXBUD-RR7-N5-e-mkSBEoDjBIwpFAT4l-WCe-lgw9TMs_k55zbDKfx08HtVKQUQFAz7BweRlZpIncoxeUnIKFLbKa_QFQ27C0_IwE_aRG7kB8BgZESU1VjNPTI6zwmK_f-huVfSeZ2hTPX43cB9jvA8h6GgDwmi7OXIKviwsoqq0YrV1fwPjxbTRyDMaJSp2b2AG-gp5XhoOr_lkHZ-nguahdAJtYNKNHoIYcWax-LLQOo1Lex7H4Na3Bb5WFHVcyC9Ueg7WksxMvBGmnc3RCeviY46ryJ8ovNBxbt_84_-R8hCl2IrOsh4bGPPfoHJg5lpoawVnRD9bWzWq5JWmTTmLk1X-gqN4Akx7iBhjXf7H_AZwaQOjlWPiVX_PtwprHa4CBABGACzpLqp31zmlgQWeESbLirY8Mq4aPtSAZEaqTHyxIVZpOBpFB7PSClhKqJRvR1sGmsHLxrEqB62uqzF3fk9cn-RossKslqn5hSyoiOs89ZNYQsFLB2YlN9vw_jI82tGPHlwlzMj61kiNMw12zhQLTHhDW2peLhxR-F_vwKzkyVU2vJvIMt5rAYKD8fjNsnW-VmugEsme4KhbBDX_hhcWxBLq68btbcO1aTolqI_B1HBQ,,&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejY4cHFySjRXSWhXUHBmLXZPMVE5QlN2TEFmaTd0S21HVk96TV9Wdk9TSDZqb1p4QWZkN2JMNjVYMjRJSHA4S0xkaUNuVVZsUGhaUFRaanFYVkZpRHlNa0JTMzl4Vmk4WGNzc0d4WktnVUtjZHVMOXRSNWRKbGp0d2pGX0NmTlk0Yyw,&sign=7e2300f0608b0aaa0f61c355b7e938e7&keyno=0&b64e=2&ref=orjY4mGPRjk5boDnW0uvlrrd71vZw9kpjly_ySFdX80,&l10n=ru&cts=1518113104136&mc=1.584962500721156) function in the standard library

```
(let [a {:a true :b true :c true :d true :e true}
      b {:c true :d true :e true :f true}
      b-keys (keys b)]
  (select-keys a b-keys))
#=> {:c true, :d true, :e true}
```

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Apart from [select-keys](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/select-keys), [min-key](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/min-key) is also useful. This function can be used with an arbitrary number of map

```
(defn min-merge [& ms]
  (let [min-keys (keys (apply min-key count ms))]
    (select-keys (apply merge ms) min-keys)))
```

Try

```
user=> (min-merge {:a 1 :b 2} {:a 3} {:a 4 :b 5 :c 6})
{:a 4}
```